# How to pass variables from test code to APEX

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to test my Apex code to get over 75% code coverage.

I have the following code:

```
@isTest
private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass3 {    
    static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails3() {
       Query_and_upload myLicenseGenerator2 = new Query_and_upload();

       myLicenseGenerator2.save(First_Name__c='Steve',Last_Name__c='Mark', Email__c='stevemark@gmail.com');     
    }
}
```

The Apex code has a PageReference sub called save and I need to pass the first name, last name and the email address.

```
public with sharing class Query_and_upload {
  public PageReference save() {    
    if(inquery.first_name__c.length() == 0 && inquery.last_name__c.length() == 0 && inquery.email__c.length() == 0 ){  
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'One of the inputs to filter the user is missing. Please enter all the fields.'));
   }
 }
```

But im getting the following error:

> Error Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: First_Name__c at
>   line

How can I pas the name and email to the save subroutine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how test methods work.

You need to actually create test data for your test code.  Assuming your fields are referring to a Contact, and that Contact is a property in your class, then you actually need to create the contact first, and then test the save method

**In your test Class**

```
Contact c = new Contact(First_Name__c='Steve',Last_Name__c='Mark', Email__c='stevemark@gmail.com');
insert c;

Query_and_upload myLicenseGenerator2 = new Query_and_upload();
myLicenseGenerator2.myContact = c;

myLicenseGenerator2.save();
```

Assuming you use a controller property for the contact in your Query_and_upload class

```
public with sharing class Query_and_upload {

    public Contact myContact      {get;set;}

    public Query_and_upload(){
        myContact = new Contact();
    }  

    public PageReference save() {    
        if(myContact.first_name__c.length() == 0 
           && myContact.last_name__c.length() == 0 
           && myContact.email__c.length() == 0 ){  
                 ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,
            'One of the inputs to filter the user is missing. Please enter all the fields.'));
    }
}
```

> Its also worth noting that altough this will increase your code
>   coverage, you really need to add some assertions so you are actually
>   'testing' the class.  This will get you coverage, but you really
>   aren't testing if the class accomplishes its goal

.

**Check out this article on testing best practices**
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

> EDIT

An example assertion

Your class has a Contact controller property that upon class instantiation, will be a new contact, with no Id.

**In your test class**

```
Contact c = new Contact(First_Name__c='Steve',Last_Name__c='Mark', Email__c='stevemark@gmail.com');
insert c;

Query_and_upload myLicenseGenerator2 = new Query_and_upload();
system.assertEquals(null, myLicenseGenerator2.myContact.Id);

myLicenseGenerator2.myContact = c;
system.assertEquals(c.Id, myLicenseGenerator2.myContact.Id);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the myContact represents in myLicenseGenerator2.myContact = c;?

Comment: That's an assumption I made in your code.  Assuming you use a controller property to store the contact you are referencing on the VF page.  I added a few lines of code to show you

Comment: Great, finally im getting somewhere, But its still confusing how to add assertions!! can you please give me one example, it would be a great help?

Comment: Added a simple example assertion to the answer above